# search monodb using number from nodejs using mongojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am using `mongojs` in `nodejs` to access `mongodb`.
I am trying to find records based on the "SOLUTION_TEST Number" as the where condition.

```
    db.stories.find({"SOLUTION_TEST Feature" : req.query.data},function(e,docs){
        console.log(docs);
        if(docs[0]){
            res.end(docs[0]);
        }
        else{
            res.end();
        }    
    });
```

According to `mongojs`, i have to pass string into the where clause. that where i pass req.query.data which is string. but i want ot pass an `number` because that feild type is a number.
from the shell i am able to make the call successfully.

How can i pass the value as a number so that mongodb understands?

Entries in stories DB:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a sample doc from your `stories` collection?

Comment: @JohnnyHK i have added a pic which shows 1 of the entry. there are many entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to parse `req.query.data` into a number; you can use `parseInt` for that.  But you also need to convert `docs[0]` to a string before passing it to `res.end`:

```
db.stories.find({"SOLUTION_TEST Feature" : parseInt(req.query.data, 10)},function(e,docs){
    console.log(docs);
    if(docs[0]){
        res.end(JSON.stringify(docs[0]));
    }
    else{
        res.end();
    }    
});
```

Comment: i have tried that. it gives an `error`.

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer

Comment: @Gyandeep Which function call is generating that error?

Comment: please view this jsfiddlle: [http://jsfiddle.net/32Pra/](http://jsfiddle.net/32Pra/)
  i have pasted the whole error there

Comment: it worked, Awesome. but the error message was very misleading about to pass string or maybe i was super dumb. thanks anyways.